# Windows on Internal HDD and Ubuntu on external HDD

Tags: hard-drive

I'm just trying to see if I understand this process correctly:

1. Download the ISO
2. Move to a bootable USB
3. Reboot
4. Plug in external HDD
5. Partition.

From here on out, I should be able to run windows if I don't have my external HDD attached and run Ubuntu otherwise correct?

Answer (score 1):

**FIRST**, you cannot move the ISO to your USB drive... It won't boot that way. You need to use some software to write its content to your USB drive. You can use Win32 Disk Imager (https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) for that. If you do this step correctly with the official Ubuntu image, your USB flash drive will become bootable.

**SECOND**, If you are **NOT using UEFI**, in other words, if your Windows HDD is MBR, when you are asked to choose the location to install "grub", make sure you don't install it on your internal HDD (which is usually `sda`). If you do so, when you boot from your internal drive without your external HDD, the grub loader will not be able to load the grub menu - and you will not boot into any OS. If possible, install "grub" to your external drive. (Not sure what it is like for UEFI booting though...)

Comment: So I went through the steps listed for installation. My laptop right now runs a Windows 10 OS on it and it boots using UFEI. I booted into Ubuntu the first time using a bootable USB, and installed Ubuntu on my external HDD. But now, every time I restart my laptop, it boots right into windows even though my HDD is plugged in.

Comment: @LostStudent Can you boot into your Ubuntu HDD manually using the boot menu? What partition table do you have on your external HDD? Is it GPT or MBR?